# Command to check IPV6=yes in ufw is in effect

Tags: networking, security, internet-security, ufw

We can set `IPV6=yes` by editing `/etc/default/ufw` to support monitoring of `ipv6` packet transfer. But it will take effect only after `ufw` is disabled and enabled or reloaded.

The question is **Is there a command/way to know that `IPV6=yes` is in effect?**

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb here but try `sudo ufw verbose` from what I understand you are checking if it's enabled.